# Screen capture in android

Tags: android

I have successfully captured the screen with following code.

```
View v1 = relativeView.getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();
```

But with this code whole screen is capturing. I want to capture only the components of a particular layout or area. Is this possible in android? Please some body help.

Comment: hey i know it's been a long time since this post.. i copied this code  `View v1 = relativeView.getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();` but relativeView is not known...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I got from your question suppose you have ImageView on your RelativeLayout and you want the snap of that Imageview not the whole RelativeLayout than you have nothing to do.

Just use your code only instead of using relativelayout use that View lets say ImageView in this case

```
ImageView v1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mImage);
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();
```